# Edit data before sending with ngResource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-resource, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

Hey I want to change the data before sending it with ngResource (build FormData object). I do everything as in the examples that I found, however I can't make them work. Here is my code:

My controller where I set the data and try to send them:

```
        var vm = this;
        vm.application = new Application();
        vm.application.title = 'Test title';
        Application.save({}, vm.application, function(){

        });
```

My service:

```
function application(ApiBaseUrl, $resource) {
    var actions = {
        'save': {
            metod: 'POST',
            url: ApiBaseUrl + "/applications",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': false },
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                console.log(data); //Returns 'undefined'
                return data;
            }
        }
    };
    return $resource(ApiBaseUrl + "applications/:id", {}, actions);
}
```

In the function `transformRequest` data object is always marked as 'undefined'. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to edit the data before sending it?

Comment: Have you tried: `Application.save(vm.application, function(){});` ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried this one. In this case the data is send as a query string and object in function transformRequest is still 'undefined'.

Comment: Have you logged the content of `vm.application` before the `Application.save(vm.application, function(){});` call?

Comment: Yes, this is what I got: `Resource {title: "Test title"}`

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `vm.application = new Application();`, as Application seems to be your AngularJS Service. You might want to try out `vm.application = {};` and then `vm.application.title = 'Test title';`.. does it work then?

Comment: The idea comes from this page [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/). I changed to `vm.application = {};` and still I get the same.

Comment: And have you tried `vm.application = new Application();` and `vm.application.data = {"title": 'Test title'};`?

Comment: Still the same. I did the test and added to the $resource parametr `data: {test: 1}`. Then the object is displayed. It looks like the data is not being bind properly, but I do not know why. Everything is done according to the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had

```
metod: 'POST'
```

when I should have used:

```
method: 'POST'
```